# Open Source web based Inventory

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm currently looking for an opensource web based inventory. I saw a few like `GLPI` and `OCS Inventory NG` but don't have much idea about it as I have not used one before. Please give your suggestions.

My requiremets:

A simple and easy to use inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not that many alternatives, but we can still build a list:

[**GPLI**](http://www.glpi-project.org/?lang=en) + [**OCS**](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/) - this is the most common set up on Debian based distributions. Since you are new to this field I would advise you to start here, counting on its large community.

[**Pulse 2**](https://www.mandriva.com/en/products-services/pulse2/) - a project by Mandriva that looks very mature with lots of features. In principle also backed by a strong community, but concieved for a different distribution.

[**Snipe IT**](http://snipeitapp.com/) - recent, with not that many features, but uses Bootstrap and looks very nice.

[**FusionInventory**](http://www.fusioninventory.org/overview/) - this is an alternative to OCS, meaning that you will still need GPLI to keep a centralised inventory.

*Extra*: There is a recent GPLI + OCS installation guide at [Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-glpi-it-and-asset-managemet-software-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

this a very late reply, but it's still a common result that pops up within the first page or two of a search engine.

[Snipe IT](http://www.snipeitapp.com/) has come a very long way since this post was answered originally, and it's well worth a look if people are interested in a clean web based asset management system.

The app also has an install script that will aid in the installation of Snipe IT for Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS.

Hope this helps future visitors.