# Free open source inventory management/invoicing software?

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

I'm looking for a free software solution for my shop. 
Basically, I need it to make invoices, manage the stock and a client db.
If there is possibility to link it to a webshop, it's a plus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Source web based Inventory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516144/open-source-web-based-inventory)

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Considering its hard to know exactly what you would need for your shop i would recommend finding a software that fits you using [Alternative to](http://alternativeto.net/software/quickbooks/) You can try out things like GnuCash (kinda like quickbooks) and see what fits your needs. If you would like to try GnuCash open the software center and search for GnuCash.

Comment: Thanks DnrDevil. Alternative to is helpful. It's a furniture shop (retail). I'm looking for a free software that does invoicing and stock/inventory control. Odoo seems to this and much more but it's not free. I'm looking into Dolibarr.

Comment: No problem, im glad to help you get installed when you find one you are looking to try (if you cant figure out how to)